Dismissible background and secondaryBackground clip behaviour
I am trying to change the way the background and secondaryBackground are shown during flutter's Dismissible animation.
The best way i found to express this is via images. When you swipe the dismissible towards the right, background starts displaying. To the left, it's secondaryBackground.
Say we place them logically like this :

Right now when i swipe right, background is static behind and starts displaying like


(starting from its left side)

if i swipe left, secondaryBackground is static behind and starts displaying like this


(starting from its right side)

However what i would like is for both background and secondaryBackground to slide into view instead
like this :


(sliding from its right side)



(sliding from its left side)

Additional information : Because i did set rezideDuration to zero, there is no animation after the dismiss. Therefore i would like the background element to take the space of the current Dismissible and vice versa with secondaryBackground.
Thank you for your time.
